# How to setup database in SQL Server by an unknown file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Probably this is the lamest question ><

I am developing an ASP.net web app with SQL Server database. When the client asked me to develop the system, he provided a file for the database.

I thought the file was a dumpfile (if you familiar with oracle or mysql, you can replicate database with dumpfile, which is basically bunch of queries inside a text file).

To my horror, plus with my noobity in SQL Server, I found out that it was NOT a dumpfile. The file is rename to .bak which is not really the correct extension for SQL Server. I tried to rename it to .mdf, but no luck.

What should I do? The client is out for vacation on some island and cannot be contacted at the moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is backup file, you need to restore database from backup.

[How to: Restore a Database Backup (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is SQL Server backup database file. You can restore it by following these steps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx

Comment: Thanks, rated you up. Wished I could click more than one answer in a question.

Answer (score 0):

Alex Aza has the right answer. But remember to create users for the database, before you restore the provided .bak file. A backup file only hold a user id -- the complete user definition is held in the server instance. Thus, it is better to create the users needed before restoring a backup from another server instance which is the case in your project.

Comment: If the database is a complete unknown, they're unlikely to know which logins/users are expected until they've done the restore.

Comment: @Damien:True, I didn't think of that. There is a way out though. Create the users after restore and run some built-in stored procedure to reconnect the user of the instance and the login of the restored database. Trouble is, that I've forgot the name of the stored procedure, and I'm only on the web by phone until monday

Comment: @Morten `sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix','<username>'`. I've had to do this so many times, it practially types itself these days :-|

Comment: @Damien: Exactly the one! One up for that :o)

Comment: Now I am having problem setting up user :(. Asp.net says that the user is not associated to a trusted SQL server

Comment: try "sp_change_users_login 'update_one', 'xxx', 'xxx'" where xxx is the username